# start capturing with command line in libpcap format

Tags: wireshark, tshark

I try to start capturing with Wireshark using command line but the default output file is `pcap` extension but Wireshark - `pcapng` file type and I need `libpcap` file type.
My command is

```
tshark.exe" -i interfacenumber -W MyFile.pcap
```

I also tried

```
tshark.exe" -i 1 -F libpcap -W MyFile.pcap
```

and in this case no file created on my disk although I can see the packets in the command line window

Answer (score 2):

```
tshark.exe -i 1 -F libpcap -w MyFile.pcap`
```

is the right answer (note the lower case 'w').

(`-W` does something different. There's lot's of tshark options, so you need to look carefully at the `tshark -h` output to make sure you're using the right option).

Answer (score 0):

Since the `-F libpcap` option is not working for me either, I'm using another command line tool in the same directory:

`editcap -F libpcap currentFile.pcap(ng) libpcapConvertedFile.pcap` where "currentFile.whatever" is the pcapng-formatted file and "libpcapConvertedFile.whatever" is the outputted legacy libpcap format.

I run this once tshark is done capturing the original file.

Comment: This is a bug: https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9991 . It will be fixed so that `-F libpcap` creates a file  in `pcap` format

Answer (score 0):

I think that in the newest `Wireshark` versions (1.8.x or 1.10.x) you cannot start capturing in `libpcap format` and the default format is `pcapng` (also pcap extension - try to use verion 1.6.x)
That's what solve my problem

http://www.wireshark.org/download/win64/all-versions/

http://www.wireshark.org/download/win32/all-versions/

Comment: This is a bug: bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9991 . It will be fixed so that `-F libpcap` creates a file in `pcap` format

Comment: I've fixed the bug; Specifying '-F libpcap' (1.8) or '-F pcap' (1.10 & newer) will create the proper format file). The fix will be available shortly in the next releases of Wireshark 1.8 and Wireshark 1.10 (to be released shortly)